# How to specify zoom level in an OpenStreetMap query?

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to include in my software automatically generated links to www.openstreetmap.org that shows a specified address. Something like

```
<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=<MyCustomAddress>">click here to see the map</a>
```

This basic functionality is working right now, but the displayed map zoom level is a bit too high. I would like to set a custom zoom level as a get parameter. It is possible ?

I tried `https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?zoom=15&query=<MyCustomAddress>` and also `z` and `map` parameters without success, and I can't find any documentation about this on the Wiki.